# Sound issue on Dell Latitude e6540 on Ubuntu 14.04 (no sound/low volume)

Tags: 14.04, sound

Last night I attempted to play a movie via HDMI, but I had no sound via the hdmi cable.

Now, today, I have no sound via my headphones. Speakers (in built) work, no issues. Headphones? No. Full volume in alsamixer, no issues I can see in pavucontrol. Figured I would just purge these and re-install them.

After accidentally purging some dependencies I have got my system settings and sound back.

But the headphone volume is still way too low. If I try a gains boost, I just get massive distortion. Speakers work fine, haven't tried with other headphones but there is nothing wrong with these ones.

I'm running a dell latitude e6540. Was working beautifully yesterday. Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: In alsamixer, did you select soundcard pressing F6, as the default soundcard is often the HDMI output?